# Maximum number of concurrent requests in solr server can handle

Tags: apache, solr, solr4

How many requests apache solar server can handle at the same time concurrently.
how can i configure solar to concurrently handle all requests.

Answer (score 0):

That's an incredible hard question to answer. It all depends on definition of "concurrently" in general, but also on how fast the queries actually are.

The number of true parallel requests is handled by the thread pool size. I believe that's somewhere in Jetty's configuration file, though I never heard of anybody increasing it.

If the queries are processed quick, the other incoming queries just queue-up on the network level and get processed next.

The real question is probably how to have the best throughput, which means tuning your queries, your caches, your disk access (e.g. SSD) and many other variables. Each of which would be a different question with a lot more specific details provided.

Comment: i don't want to queue up my queries. suppose there are 100 queries at same time. 100th person have to wait for so long. so any suggestions how can i configure solr to handle these requests

Comment: If a fully loaded server can process 10 queries in 100ms, then it can (at most) process 100 queries in 1000ms. Whether it does so by running them all in parallel or does it 10 at a time with queueing makes no difference.

Comment: thanks. what do you mean by fully loaded and how can i configure solar to handle 1000 requests at same time

Comment: There is no easy or single answer to this. You need to load-test your system (e.g. with JMeter) with realistic queries and then figure out where the bottleneck is. Then, and only then, you will know what are the right questions to ask that can actually get specific answers.

Comment: What I mean is that you don't get extra responsiveness or throughput by running 1000 concurrent requests on a server. The server has a number of physical CPU cores and when they are close to 100% usage ("fully loaded"), adding more concurrent requests will just slow things down due to extra bookkeeping and more CPU-cache misses.

Exactly how many concurrent Solr requests it takes to saturate a single CPU-core depends on your setup, but let's be generous and say 10. So unless you have a 100 CPU-core-machine, insisting on 1000 concurrent requests does not make sense.